# Enforce Message Expiration - MobileConnect

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect

What is the use of 'Enforce Message Expiration' when you configure a send blockout in Mobile Connect ?

On the Salesforce help, they don't really explain..

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 4):

`Enforce Message Expiration` cancels all SMS sends that are in progress once the blockout window starts.

Usually, sends do not pause at the send blockout:

> For example, if your send starts at 9 PM and takes two hours, and your
> send blockout starts at 10 PM, the send continues until 11 PM, into
> the send blockout time period.

Source: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_moc_send_blockouts.htm&type=5

If you check the `Enforce Message Expiration` box, it will cancel all ongoing SMS sends as soon as you hit the blockout window.